# Simulating RDS `aws_lambda.invoke_lambda` with Localstack

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, localstack

I'm trying to simulate invoking lambda functions on my computer using [LocalStack](https://localstack.cloud/) and PostgreSQL. In RDS, this can be done using the [aws_lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL-Lambda.html#PostgreSQL-Lambda-install-extension) PostgreSQL extension. I was thinking of installing the `aws_lambda` in my local Postgre and make it trigger the lambda defined in LocalStack. However, I can't seem to find a way to install the `aws_lambda` extension.

Does anybody know if the extension is open source? Can I get my hands on it? If not, is there a way to simulate lambda invocation in Localstack?

Answer (score 1):

You can use untrusted python in postgres ("plpythonu" extension) to emulate aws_lambda.
I.e. something like:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION awslambda_fn(fn_name text, fn_args text)
    RETURNS text
    AS $$
     import boto3
     import boto.utils
     region=boto.utils.get_instance_identity()['document']['region']
     client=boto3.client('lambda',region)
     response=client.invoke(FunctionName=fn_name,
                            InvocationType='RequestResponse',
                            Payload=fn_args,
                           )
     r = response['Payload'].read()
     if ( 'FunctionError' in response ):
         raise Exception(r)
     return r
   $$ language plpythonu ;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION awslambda_fn(text, text) TO PUBLIC;
```

But obviously need to copy the actual `aws_lambda.invoke()` API.

Comment: Interesting. This means that `boto3` has to be installed in the global `site-packages` right?

Comment: @AnugerahErlaut not really, you can use venv. Just need to initializae it before running postgres (systemd unit changes, probably)